# Display Bootstrap Select Groups Horizontal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grouping, bootstrap-select

I have a [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options) dropdownlist

```
<select id="example-multiple-optgroups">
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
    <option value="1-2" selected="selected">Option 1.2</option>
    <option value="1-3" selected="selected">Option 1.3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
    <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[image: BEFORE]

I try to display the groups side by side as this

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Consider of adding full code.

Comment: There is an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jX2A6/1  Thanks

Comment: Is that impossible? :(